# how to execute commands using RAW TCP connection in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, connection

while creating C# script I am able to connect to the TCP but not able to execute any command like login etc...

sample command to execute RQ01,R01,10,CLI,CNUM

on a side note I am able to get response using PuTTY from above command but not able to execute command in C# code.

My code:

```
try {
    // Create a TcpClient.
    // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
    // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
    // combination.
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("xxx.xxx.xx.x", 2131);
    var message = "LOGIN,10,SUGARDEV,CLEF";
    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
    //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

    // Receive the TcpServer.response.

    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
    data = new Byte[256];

    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
    String responseData = String.Empty;

    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
    //var message = "LOGIN,10,SUGARDEV,CLEF";
    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    //Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
    //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();


    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    // Close everything.
    //stream.Close();
    //client.Close();
} catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
}
Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");

Console.Read();
```

Comment: What server program is listening on port 2131?

Comment: Your receive code is extremely buggy. How can you be sure you received the whole message in one Read operation?

Comment: it is an ERP API solution.
@Fildor can you please share some sample code for this. i do not have much hands on experience on TCP communications

Comment: Please do some research on the net. There should be plenty examples and tutorials available. For SO it is off topic to provide tutorials. Also, being unfamiliar with the protocol in use, any example code would be incomplete at best.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to select if you'll be using asynchronous or synchronous communication.  Synchronous is the easiest, where you send the command and wait for the response to arrive.  Then you could have a state machine defining where you are in the communication process:

1. SendCommand - Send the command using stream.Write()
2. AwaitResponse - Wait in a while loop for the response to arrive, or time out after a set time period.
3. ParseResponse - Validate that the response is what you expect, and perhaps retransmit the command if the response is incorrect (checksum fail, etc.).

Or you could use asynchronous communication, where you send the command and don't wait for a response - the response will be handled by other code.  Then you need a RX handler in a separate thread, that's all the time awaiting incoming data, and sending it into some buffer.  Then, after sending a command, you can carry on doing other stuff and check back later to see if a response has arrived.

EDIT: My preference is normally asynchronous communication, as it causes the least lag in the application.  How to implement it depends on the communication protocol, and if it's e.g. an ASCII string or a complex binary protocol.

Here's a snippet from the RX handler of an asynchronous implementation.  This is a binary protocol on a serial communication line, so it's necessary to validate each received byte, one by one.

```
public class Message
{
    public Message()
    {
        Payload = new Payload();
        RawData = new List<byte>();
    }

    public byte Address { get; set; }
    public byte Length { get; set; }
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }
    public byte Checksum { get; set; }
    public List<byte> RawData { get; set; }
}

enum RxState
{
    AwaitStartCharacter,
    AwaitLengthCharacters,
    AwaitPayloadCharacters,
    AwaitChecksumCharacters
}

private void RxBufferQueueConsumer()
{
    var rxState = RxState.AwaitStartCharacter;
    Message rxMessage = null;
    while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        CheckRxBufferQueue(ref rxState, ref rxMessage);
    }
}

private BlockingCollection<byte> _rxBufferQueue;
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private void CheckRxBufferQueue(ref RxState rxState, ref Message rxMessage)
{
    byte rxByte;
    if (_rxBufferQueue.TryTake(out rxByte, 50))
    {
        switch (rxState)
        {
            case RxState.AwaitStartCharacter:
                AwaitStartCharacter(ref rxState, rxByte, ref rxMessage);
                break;

            case RxState.AwaitLengthCharacters:
                AwaitLengthCharacters(ref rxState, rxByte, ref rxMessage);
                break;

            case RxState.AwaitPayloadCharacters:
                AwaitPayloadCharacters(ref rxState, rxByte, ref rxMessage);
                break;

            case RxState.AwaitChecksumCharacters:
                AwaitChecksumCharacters(ref rxState, rxByte, ref rxMessage);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you share a sample code. for this.

Comment: I've added an example.  How to implement it depends on your communication protocol.